# Is ANTLR Visitor the right tool for my usage

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am using ANTLR4 and here some context:

### my grammar:

I am using the made available [tsql](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/tsql/tsql.g4) grammar. I extend and modified this grammar a little bit with a few exceptions.

### my generated java classes

ANTLRWorks 2 generated me `tsql.tokens`, `tsqlBaseVisitor.java`, `tsqlParser.java` and so on

### my "MyTsqlVisitor.java"

```
import ...

public class MyTsqlVisitor extends tsqlBaseVisitor<String>{
    //here I need to implement my rules
}
```

### my Main Method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    tsqlLexer lexer = null;
    
    try {
        lexer = new tsqlLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("test.iql"));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    
    tsqlParser parser = new tsqlParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    
    ParseTree tree = parser.tsql_file();
    MyTsqlVisitor visitor = new MyTsqlVisitor();
    visitor.visit(tree);        
}
```

### my test.iql

```
begin   
    declare var_etl_log_message varchar(2000);
    declare var_etl_proc_line int;

    exception
        when others then

        set var_etl_error_message = sqlstate || errormsg ();

        resignal;
end;
```

### my question

I want use ANTLR for example to get the value of `var_etl_error_message` and then to print `system.out.println(valueOfVar);`

First of all is ANTLR the right tool for my usage? I read a lot of things about ANTLR and it looked really nice and fine for my usage. I did generated with ANTLRWorks2 a parsetree and it was perfect if I can get for example the value or the object as a String.

If yes, is my guess right, that the `Visitor` is better then the `Listener` for my usage?

If again yes ;-), then I am on the right way for my tool and I want to ask you guys because I have trouble to implement `MyTsqlVisitor.java`. Can you guys tell me a refer or something like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately stack over flow isn't the right tool to ask "is abc the best tool to do xyz; or are there others".

Comment: this is probably true but I am at my wit's end and I don't know who I can ask -- so i tried here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want use ANTLR for example to get the value of var_etl_error_message and then to print system.out.println(valueOfVar);

It seems you will have to develop a more or less working interpreter for this language. It probably won't have to be fully functional, but if you want to get the result after execution then you will have to execute it in some way (so it will be some kind of interpreter).

Yes, ANTLR is the right tool for it, but it won't necessarily be simple, especially if you are dealing with a language implementation first time. The Visitor is probably also a better choice than Listener (I'd pick Visitor too). IMO the Listener API is sufficient only for very simple usecases (like prettyprinting or extracting comments).

Comment: I am understanding what you try to put outside but in your answer is something supportive (that it is possible) and something scarry ^^ the biggest problem is I dont know how I will start with my `MyTsqlVisitor.java` because the grammar isn't mine

Comment: Well if you don't mind I won't dig into the grammar and I won't give you concrete code. Instead you may look into an old hobby project of mine: https://github.com/erosb/pascal
This is a skeletal-prototypal interpreter for a pascal-like language, and it is visitor-based. It can serve as an example of things like control structure interpretation, expression evaluation, basic symbol table management. Of course it is only good to give you ideas, it isn't perfect and isn't functional.

Comment: I can also recommend the following books, if you have time for looking into them: The definitive ANTLR4 reference; Language implementation patterns

Comment: first of all thank you to give me an example. I already ordered this book :)